# How to disable print pop up with JavaScript after pressing CTRL + P

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$(document).bind("keyup keydown", function (e) {
        if (e.ctrlKey && (e.key == "p" || e.charCode == 16 || e.charCode == 112 || e.keyCode == 80)) {
            e.cancelBubble = true;
            e.preventDefault();

 return Print();
        }
    });
```

I tried above code it works for chrome , Mozilla but not for Internet Explorer. In IE print dialog is coming after that my Print() is calling.

Please suggest.

Comment: Maybe `e.ctrlKey && e.key == 'p'`?

Comment: the problem is print dialog box is coming after that my print () is calling, I don't want to display print dialog. Its only happening in IE only

Answer (score 0):

As Internet Explorer doesn't support preventDefault(), your best best is something like the below:

```
if (e.preventDefault) //checks for the presence of the preventDefault function
{
   e.preventDefault() // calls the function
}
else
    if (/keypress logic goes here/) {
        window.event.returnValue = null;
        event.keyCode=0; // if the keyCode is 0, IE will not execute the command.
    }
```

So when a browser supports preventDefault (Chrome, Firefox, etc), simply call that. Where it doesn't (IE), set the keyCode to a value that won't perform the original function (preventing the print dialog from appearing).

Comment: It's not working Print dialog is coming after that. please suggest any way to suppress the print dialog after pressing Ctr+p key press.